# Give more relevance to the title in search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

How can I give more relevance to the title in search results in SharePoint?

Comment: I believe the `Title` field is the primary search file for SharePoint Search results. I believe it's specifically the default `Title` field rather than any field named "Title" in your list.

Comment: How can I access and modify the search?

Answer (score 3):

In the page, you could edit the page and edit the search result web part to modify the search result.

And in the site, we can go to site settings->search to modify the search.

You could access and modify the search in SharePoint admin center like the picture below.

[image]

More references:

[Change settings for the Search Results Web Part.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-settings-for-the-search-results-web-part-40ff85b3-bc5e-4230-b1dd-f088188e487e)

[SharePoint Online search administration overview.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-the-admin-center)